# The image cannot be removed as it has been assigned to the other image role?

Tags: magento2, admin, product-images, image

I am using `Magento 2.1.4` unable to remove the image while removing it noticing "**The image cannot be removed as it has been assigned to the other image role**".

How can I overcome this?

I have searched on Google but didn't get any proper result and fix for this could you please provide me any suggestions.

Thanks in advance[image: The image cannot be removed as it has been assigned to the other image role]

Answer (score 20):

Switch to each store and try deleting the image from there.

Comment: i have tried the same, but image  still existing in the images section and getting the same notice message.

Comment: Did you switch to store or store view ?

Comment: i have switched from all store views to store and removed the image and save the product. http://prntscr.com/ev1dco

Comment: I am also looking for same, Images also not deleting in store_view

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7647

Comment: i follow as instructions but still its not working... also i just watch in database new image uploaded with "tmp" like test.jpg.tmp ?

Answer (score 13):

You need to switch to each store and then uncheck the product image role like small, large from product description and the try to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

running the sql

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id in (87,88,89,154)
and store_id <> 0
```

will find all product ids and gallery images in your catalog that are not set to the default store. If you delete all of the results in bulk will eliminate the error in deleting products in the future. You can expend the query to include specific product ID's to suite your needs.

based on this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785864/magento-2-change-image-role-from-db

Answer (score 1):

This is a magento bug for multistore/multi website
You just have to delete the image from all of the store view
It will work for sure :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure the image is not in other stores ... 
in my case i had two websites for multiple languages 
just unchecked product in website > main website then save 
then remove image and save again.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to each store and successfully deleted the image from the product page. I then flushed the cache and it worked perfectly!

Thanks for your help